Report Viewer Task not giving option to choose Reports in Visual basic 2022 VB.NET
Error While installing newer version of Reporting Service Winform(https://i.sstatic.net/FyJwP7KV.png)
warn : NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms 150.1652.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8.1' instead of the project target framework 'net8.0-windows7.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
warn : NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms 10.0.40219.1' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8.1' instead of the project target framework 'net8.0-windows7.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
warn : NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types 14.0.1016.290' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8.1' instead of the project target framework 'net8.0-windows7.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
info : Package 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms' is compatible with all the specified frameworks in project 'E:\New folder\Stock Managament\Stock Managament.vbproj'.
I want to show reports data in the application

Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms only supports .NET Framework projects. If you want ReportViewr for .NET 5+ , or .NET Core 3.1+ you may want to use ReportViewer Core.
